# Why am I getting this error from wild card (from) contains 100 problem, while importing tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, module, tk-toolkit

After importing `tkinter` I am getting this problem in in my Visual Studio Code when I write this

```
import tkinter as Tk
from tkinter import *
```

it showing that from contains 100 error from wildcard. I have installed tkinter but seems help less I am get shocked by seeing 100 problem from wildcard for writing only one word (from).

I have googled it but there also seems no answer. I go to check for similar problem, but maybe only I'm getting this error.

I am using Python version 3.7.3. I am getting no error but problem in only (from).

Comment: i guess its because,`from tkinter import * ` imports everything from tkinter that are not being used in your project and hence it gives such warning, but it wont throw any error while code execution

Comment: Exactly, You can ignore it tho. Won't affect your code

Comment: Why are you importing `tkinter` twice?

Comment: You don't need the second line. You are already importing tkinter, you shouldn't be importing it twice in two different ways.

Comment: thanks for telling me it works but i am not able to understand why  i am getting the problem